# Column sum printed in the times of row size

Tags: java, jsp, jdbc

I'm writing a JDBC program where I need to get a sum of a particular column.

When I do a `sysout`, the result that is getting printed is correct, but the problem is, it is getting printed row size times. My column size is 882, and the result is getting printed 882 times as `time takes s 5.75` (5.75 is the sum of that column).

Below is my code.

```
public int getTotalFromDB() throws Exception {
        Connection conn = dbConnection.getConn();
        Statement stmt, stmt1 = dbConnection.getStmt();
        ResultSet rs, rs1 = dbConnection.getRs();

        String queryString, queryString1 = null;
        dbConnection.createClassForNameForSQLServer();
        String userName = "sa";
        String password = "mypassword";
        String url = "MYDBURL";
        dbConnection.createClassForNameForSQLServer();
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, userName, password);
        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        stmt1 = conn.createStatement();
        queryString = "SELECT COUNT(*) as CNT from statusTable";
        queryString1 = "select sum([Time Taken(minutes)]) as timeTaken from statusTable";
        rs = stmt.executeQuery(queryString);
        rs.next();
        DBCount = rs.getInt("CNT");
        rs.close();
        stmt.close();
        rs1 = stmt1.executeQuery(queryString1);
        rs1.next();
        timeTaken = rs1.getFloat("timeTaken");
        rs1.close();
        stmt1.close();
        System.out.println("Time taken s " + timeTaken);
        return DBCount;
    }
```

The code calling it is as below.

**JSP**

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">

</head>
<body>

    <form action="GetTheCounts" method="get" id="form1">
        <div class="status">
            <span class="totalTime">Count is ${DAOCount}/${excelCount}</span> <span
                class="efficiency"></span>
        </div>
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.getElementById("form1").submit();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Controller**

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    GetTheCountsDAO getTheCountsDAO = new GetTheCountsDAO();
    try {
        int excelCount = getTheCountsDAO.getTotalFromExcel();
        int DAOCount = getTheCountsDAO.getTotalFromDB();
        request.setAttribute("DAOCount", DAOCount);
        request.setAttribute("excelCount", excelCount);
        request.getRequestDispatcher("counts.jsp").forward(request, response);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

please let me know where am I going wrong and how can I print this only once.

Thanks

Comment: Your method is running multiple times. Can you post the code calling it?

Comment: Have you tried adding a `rowcount = 1`?

Comment: 882 *columns*? Are you sure you do not mean rows? Most likely a loop calling the method where you iterate over the whole table or something similar.

Comment: Hi @shmosel, updated my question with the other .code

Comment: Hi @LordAnomander, sorry my bad, That was the number of rows. Thanks for poking it. Updated my question with other files as well.

Answer (score 0):

**Use this code**
 *This code can help u to print sum of the column values in each row and return the column count.*

```
while(rs1.next())
{

        timeTaken = rs1.getFloat("timeTaken");
         System.out.println("Time taken s " + timeTaken);
}

return DBCount;
```

Comment: Hi Simbu, the result is same

Comment: Actually what's ur requirement.you need to fetch the count or sum of timeTaken for each column.Please just tell ur requirement,i can give soln to this issue.

Comment: Hi, i need to get the sum.

Comment: select sum(timetaken) as time_Taken from statusTable group by id. (ie) here id is one of the field of ur table.so replace idinstead of one field from ur table.Then return tikeTaken to the result.